# How to search for a string in java and the numbers proceeding it

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader, ping

I'm currently wondering how I would go about search for a specific string and finding the numbers proceeding it. I have a program that checks the ping on the ip you type in and it comes out with max, min, average etc. I am currently trying to see if there is a way to find and print out just the max, min and average numbers. I've tried manually checking the charAt but it ends up coming up to about 15 lines of unnecessary code when it should only be a few. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a picture of the numbers i'm trying to get:

[image]

Here is the code I am using to find the ping

```
public static void runSystemCommand(String command, JTextArea field) {
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String s = "";
        // reading output stream of the command
        while ((s = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried with regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    String s = "Minimum: 672ms, Maximum: 696ms,...time=675ms ... ";
    // the following code will match the first two numbers but not the third! 
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s\\d+ms");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group().trim());
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
672ms
696ms
```

Comment: Thank you!, it works really well. I didn't even think if just searching for numbers followed with the ms.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following strategy:

1. parse the line on commas (perhaps adding an ending comma)
2. parse each resulting segment on the =
3. get the name (minimum/maximum/.) by trimming first piece; get integer time by parsing second string taking the part of the string from 0 to where you find "ms"